# How does Redis Rails authentication work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, authlogic, redis

I'm spinning my wheels a little bit here trying to learn Redis which itself is fairly easy to understand. I don't know much about how Sessions work with a key-value data store like Redis-store. I'd like to use either Authlogic or Devise. The later seems possible while it's configurable with Rack::Session, but at this point I'm a little lost.

I'd love to see an example of basic authentication or other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`redis-store` provides an interface for `Rack::Session` to use when creating sessions. If you install `redis-store` then this should only require changing your cache store like this:

```
config.cache_store = :redis_store
```

Then your sessions will be stored inside the Redis instance. I am a bit confused on why you are asking about authentication considering that this really has nothing to do with user authentication alone, but involves changing how Rails stores session data which is used by your authentication layer to validate the client once they are logged in.

Comment: As I said, I'm a little confused on redis authentication schemes in general, but familiar with redis-store. I just assumed there was a pattern like authlogic or devise available to Redis that managed all this.

Comment: Who is authenticating to Redis and why?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how an enduser logins, and is able to perform actions against a NOSQL backend in Rails. That's actually pretty much it, i'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What do you mean? You want them to have direct access to a database and be able to run commands on it?

Comment: Let's break this down. There's no gem yet like Authlogic or Devise for Redis, right. I've never rolled my own authentication sadly, so I'm unclear how you set the cookie (redis-store). I'm just confused how you persist an authenticated user with Redis and if-where-what you store in a nosql db. Hope that's clearer.

Comment: Ok so you want user persistance on the site? This information is stored in a session and devise and authlogic already use sessions to store information, When you install the `redis-store` nothing needs to change with devise or authlogic. You just need to tell Rails that you are using Redis and it is taken care of.